# Is data.sql disabled in spring boot 2.3.1.RELEASE?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DatabaseDemoApplication  implements CommandLineRunner  {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    PersonJbdcDao dao;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DatabaseDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
//      Thread.sleep(1000);  --------------------------------------------------> line 1
        logger.info("All users -> {}", dao.findAll());
    }
}

@Repository
public class PersonJbdcDao {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Person> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from person", 
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Person>(Person.class));
    }
}
```

In `pom.xml`

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I am using h2 database. Following is the `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

Person.class

```
private int id;
private String name;
private String location;
private Date birthDate;

// getter and setter
```

I also have a `data.sql` file in the resources folder which have create and insert statements.
If i keep line 1(Thread.sleep(1000)) commented and run the project I'm facing an error but I am able to access table Person via h2 console

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from person]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PERSON" not found; SQL statement:
select * from person [42102-200]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PERSON" not found; SQL statement:
select * from person [42102-200]
```

I have 2 scenarios

1. If I keep line 1 commented and rename `data.sql` file to `schema.sql` file everything works perfect. I'm able to access why is that?
2. If I keep `data.sql` file and don't rename it I have to uncomment line 1 to get application working. Why is that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Spring Boot 2.3, [JPA repository initialization is "deferred"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#bootstrapmode-for-jpa-repositories).
So `run` method runs before initialized it (if you don't define any JPA repositories).

If set

```
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default
```

on `application.properties`, run as you expected.

see also:

- [9.10.3. Initialize a Database using basic SQL scripts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc)

---

[`DataSourceInitializerInvoker` javadoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java#L31-L33) says:

> Bean to handle `DataSource` initialization by running `schema-*.sql` on `InitializingBean#afterPropertiesSet()` and `data-*.sql` SQL scripts on `DataSourceSchemaCreatedEvent`.

, and [`DataSourceSchemaCreatedEvent`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceSchemaCreatedEvent.java#L24-L26) says:

> This happens when `schema-*.sql` files are executed or when Hibernate initializes the database.

So, on first scenario, `data.sql` is executed after JPA(Hibernate) initialization, but it is "deferred".
On the other hand, `schema.sql` is executed before `run()`, same as earlier version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please answer why does it work it first scenario. just by renaming ?